# Class template, allow user to define type C++

Tags: c++, templates, types, defined

I am doing a project about open addressed hash tables using vectors. One aspect of this project is to use templates to allow the user to define a type for the vector. I have implemented the template and it works if I create an object before compiling, however I cannot figure out how to allow the user to decide the type during runtime.

The program is object orientated and the type has to be passed into the constructor. At first I thought simple if statements would work, however I have since learned that this does not work. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std; 

template <class T>
class OpenHash 
{
private: 
vector <T> hashTab;
vector <int> emptyCheck;
int hashF(string);

public:
OpenHash(int);
int getVectorCap();
int addRecord (T);
int sizeHash();
int find(T);
int printHash();
int deleteEntry(T);

};

template <class T>
OpenHash<T>::OpenHash(int vecSize)
{
 hashTab.clear();
 hashTab.resize(vecSize);
 emptyCheck.resize(vecSize);
        for (int i=0; i < emptyCheck.capacity(); i++)   
        {
        emptyCheck.at(i) = 0;

        }
}

template <class T>
int OpenHash<T>::getVectorCap()
{

 int cap = hashTab.capacity();
 int capE = emptyCheck.capacity();
 cout << cap << capE;
return 0;
}

template <class T>
int OpenHash<T>::hashF (string key)
{
int ascii = 0, hasVal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < key.size(); i++)
        {
            ascii += key[i]; 
        }
hasVal = ascii % hashTab.capacity();
return hasVal;
}

template <class T>
int OpenHash<T>::addRecord(T key)
{
if (sizeHash() == emptyCheck.size())
{
    cout << "Your hash table is full cannot add any more records" << endl;
}

else
{
    bool findPos = false;

    for (int j=0; j<hashTab.capacity(); j++)
    {
        if (hashTab.at(j) == key)
        {
            cout << "Element ready exists in hashtable" << endl;
            return 0;
        }

    }
    int hashVal = hashF(key);

        for (int i=hashVal; i<emptyCheck.capacity(); i++)
        {
            if (emptyCheck.at(i) == 0)
            {
                hashTab.at(i) = key;
                emptyCheck.at(i) = 1;
                cout << "Element added at" << '[' << i << ']' <<  endl;
                findPos = true;
                return 0;
            }
            else 
            {
                cout << "Collision probing through..." << endl;
            }
        }

        if (findPos == false)
        {

            for (int x=0; x<emptyCheck.capacity(); x++)
            {
                if (emptyCheck.at(x) == 0)
                {
                    hashTab.at(x) = key;
                    emptyCheck.at(x) = 1;
                    cout << "Element added at" << '[' << x << ']' << endl;
                    findPos=true;
                    return 0; 
                }
            }
        cout <<  "Element could not be added" << endl;

        }


}   
return 1;
}

template <class T>
int OpenHash<T>::sizeHash()
{
int elementsFilled = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<emptyCheck.capacity(); i++)
        {
            if (emptyCheck.at(i) != 0)
                {
                    elementsFilled++;
                }
        }

return elementsFilled;

}

template <class T>
int OpenHash<T>::find(T key)
{
int hashVal = hashF(key);
bool findLoop = false;


for (int i=hashVal; i < hashTab.capacity(); i++)
{

        if (hashTab.at(i) == key && emptyCheck.at(i) == 1)  
        {
            cout << "Element found at position: " << '[' << i << ']' << endl;
            cout << key << endl;
            findLoop = true;
            return 0;
        }   

        else
        {
            cout << "Element not found at position! Probing through..."  << endl;
            }


    }       

        if (findLoop == false)   
        {


            for (int j = 0; j < hashTab.capacity(); j++)
            {

                if (hashTab.at(j) == key && emptyCheck.at(j) != 0)
                {
                    cout << "Element found at position: " << '['  << j << ']' << endl;
                    cout << key << endl;
                    findLoop = true;
                    return 0;
                }

            }
        cout << "Entry not found" << endl;
        }
return 1;

}

template <class T>
int OpenHash<T>::deleteEntry(T toDel)
{
int hashVal = hashF(toDel);
bool foundDel = false;

    for (int i = hashVal; i<hashTab.capacity(); i++)
    {
        if (hashTab.at(i) == toDel)
        {
            emptyCheck.at(i) = 0;
            foundDel = true;
            cout << "Entry deleted!" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

        if (foundDel == false)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<hashTab.capacity(); j++)
            {   
                if (hashTab.at(j) == toDel)
                {   
                    emptyCheck.at(j) = 0;
                    foundDel = true;
                    cout << "Entry deleted!" << endl;
                    return 0;

                }

            }
        cout << "The member to delete was not found" << endl;
        }   

return 1;
}

template <class T>
int OpenHash<T>::printHash()
{
if (sizeHash() == 0)
{
    cout << "No elements filled to print!" << endl; 
}

    for (int i=0; i<emptyCheck.capacity(); i++)
    {
        if (emptyCheck.at(i) != 0)
            {
                cout << "Record at:" << '[' << i << ']' <<  hashTab.at(i) << endl; 
            }   
    }
return 0;
}

int main () 
{
   cout << "Please input the size of your HashTable" << endl;
   int vecSize = 0;
   cin >> vecSize;
   OpenHash<string> newTable(vecSize);

bool menu = true;
char choice;
while (menu == true)    
{
    cout << "Welcome to the open address hash table program, please input your  choice:" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 'a')
        {
            cout << "Please type in the record you wish to add:" <<   endl;
            string rec;
            getline(cin, rec);
        newTable.addRecord(rec);
        }
        if (choice == 's')
        {
            cout << "Number of elements filled: " << newTable.sizeHash()  << endl;
        }
        if (choice == 'f')
        {
            cout << "Please enter the string you wish to find" << endl;
            string key;
            getline(cin, key)
            newTable.find(key);
        }
        if (choice == 'p')
        {
            cout << "Printing table..." << endl;
            newTable.printHash();

        }
        if (choice == 'd')
        {
            cout << "Please input the item you wish to delete:" << endl;
            string toDel;
            getline(cin, toDel)
            newTable.deleteEntry(toDel);
        }

        if (choice == 'x')
        {
            cout << "Thankyou" << endl;
            menu = false;
        }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Types aren't passed to constructors; *parameters* are (which, of course, have types, but are not "types" themselves in the language-sense). Showing your existing code will bring exponentially more clarity to this than your telling us about it.  It sounds like you have an enumerable type-like library configurable by-choice from the user, but thats sheer speculation with nothing to back it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates are "decided" during compile time.  They cannot be decided dynamically at run-time.

If you want to support certain types (e.g. `int`, `double`, `char`, etc.), you can declare them explicitly in your program and they will be compiled, but only the types you support (or others that you use in your program) will be available for the user to "pick":

```
template<typename T>
class MyTemplateClass { ... };

class template MyTemplateClass<int>;
class template MyTemplateClass<double>;
class template MyTemplateClass<char>;

int main()
{
    // if user wants to create a new int version:
    MyTemplate<int> myInt;
    // etc ...
    return 0;
}
```